# Trying to get my NVIDIA optimus card working

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I have a dell l502x laptop with the infamously screwed up hybrid graphics card system (NVIDIA GT540m and Integrated Intel GC)

I have a freshly installed ubuntustudio 16.4.01 LTS running dual boot with windows 10; After installing the proprietary, tested NVIDIA driver 361- recommended at the 'Additional Drivers' tab, a reboot gives a blank screen with the mouse stuck at the top right corner, and nothing works but a forced reboot via long-pressing the main power button.

I have tried all the different driver versions and all the different PPA repositories (xorg-edgers, graphics-drivers etc), the same issue persists.

The system however reboots successfully if the 'intel' card is selected by the command

```
    sudo prime-select intel
```

when the NVIDIA card is selected

```
    glxgears
```

gives the following error

```
    Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

command

```
    lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

gives

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller

### Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff)
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_361

```
     dkms status
```

bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-38-lowlatency, x86_64: installed
nvidia-361, 361.42, 4.4.0-38-lowlatency, x86_64: installed

```
    glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the solution you're looking for. I had a lot of problems with my Nvidia video card too and this is what worked for me.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

This will give you additional open source drivers to choose from. Just open up additional drivers and choose the one your video card needs. My video card needed 367.44

Comment: Yup, tried it, same error.   Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual